# New to Rails Help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoding

I have a database query that is returning to a variable which contains an address.

```
@terminal_address = Terminal.find(:all, :select => :full_address ,:conditions => ["id = ?" , params[:id]])
```

When I pass the `@terminal_address` to my geocoding code it errors because of how the data is being passed. If I replace the variable with an address in quotes it works fine. How can I extract the string from the variable?

This is very frustrating!

Comment: Could you please post the geocoding code? Your other code would be nice, too :)

Answer (score 4):

```
@terminal_address = Terminal.find(:first, :conditions => ["id = ?" , params[:id]]).full_address
```

This should work.

What you were doing wrong:

- You asked for :all instead of only :first of Terminals, you were given an array
- Each entry in the array was a Terminal instance with only one attribute selected (full_address)

Answer (score 2):

Uh, why not just:

```
Terminal.find_by_id!(params[:id], :select => :full_address).full_address
```

This will raise an error when the id cannot be found.

Comment: ya, conditions with "id=?" are so not rails way

Answer (score -1):

The `@terminal_address` is an instance of the `Terminal` class.  Thus, you will need to get an attribute of that class that contains the address information.  In this case, the field appears to be named 'full_address'  So something like:

```
Terminal.find(:first, :conditions => ["id = ?" , params[:id]]).full_address
```

should return the full address string